# Any way to get DocumentReference from DocumentSnapshot in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

`DocumentSnapshot` id can be fetched by this `documentSnapshot.documentID`. Similarly is there any way to get `DocumentReference` from `DocumentSnapshot` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use its [ref](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/ref.html) property.  I discovered this using [the API documentation for DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html).